# Variable returning empty in logon script

Tags: bash, scripts, kde

I'm trying to make a script that runs when the user logs in, to change the wallpaper.
I run the script at logon, the script is inside the /etc/profile.d/ folder.
I use ImageMagick to write the PC name and Teamviewer ID on the wallpaper and plasma-apply-wallpapaerimage to change the wallpaper.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
plasma-apply-wallpaperimage /home/suporte/share/win10.jpg
convert /home/suporte/share/win10.jpg -pointsize 20 -fill darkblue -annotate +1650+50 "Nome do PC:   $HOSTNAME" /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg
TVID="$(cat /var/log/teamviewer15/TeamViewer15_Logfile.log | tail -1 | grep -oP '(?<=DyngateID: )[0-9]+' | sed -r ':A;s|([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})|\1 \2|g;t A')"
convert /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg -pointsize 20 -fill darkblue -annotate +1650+80 "Teamviewer: $TVID" /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg
plasma-apply-wallpaperimage /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg
```

I also tried starting the variable and executing the command with the variable on the same line

```sh
...
TVID="$(cat /var/log/teamviewer15/TeamViewer15_Logfile.log | tail -1 | grep -oP '(?<=DyngateID: )[0-9]+' | sed -r ':A;s|([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})|\1 \2|g;t A')" convert /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg -pointsize 20 -fill darkblue -annotate +1650+80 "Teamviewer: $TVID" /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg
...
```

Or using &&

```sh
...
TVID="$(cat /var/log/teamviewer15/TeamViewer15_Logfile.log | tail -1 | grep -oP '(?<=DyngateID: )[0-9]+' | sed -r ':A;s|([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})|\1 \2|g;t A')" && convert /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg -pointsize 20 -fill darkblue -annotate +1650+80 "Teamviewer: $TVID" /home/suporte/share/wpp.jpg
...
```

The problem is that this $TVID variable that I use to pass the ID to ImageMagick always comes out empty. If I put anything in the variable, it comes out empty. Unless it is text without spaces and without quotation marks (like aaaaaaaaaaa).

I've already tried putting a separate script just to start the variable, using `export TVID=...` but the result is the same. I'm using Kubuntu 22.04.

Apart from this problem with the variable, everything works normally. As I said, if I put `TVID=aaaaaaaaaa`, ImageMagick writes *Teamviewer: aaaaaaaaaa*. The script works if I run it directly through the terminal

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is not answerable without more information. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? How is the script run at logon? Does the script work if you run it from a terminal? Do you run this scrip with or without `sudo` when run manually?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For some reason, my post is getting cut off. Even editing, when saved, it cuts again. Most part of the beginning of the original post had been cut. The Script is inside the profile.d folder. If I run the script with sudo the plasma-apply-wallpaperimage does not work.
The script works if I run it directly through the terminal

Comment: I would assume you are setting the variable in another shell.

Comment: I'm configuring the variable in the same script, as you can see in the code above. I've tried other types of code, like putting everything on the same line or using && between one and the other, but the result is the same. How can I ensure it's running in the same shell?